# Make scrollbar appear on vertical menu when page resized

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, scrollable

Having trouble with something that should be really simple. Basically, I have right-hand vertical menu wherein my client wants to have a scrollbar included on it when the page is resized to a certain point.

```
    <div id="hamburger_menu_parent">
        <span id="toggle-menu"></span>         // User clicks this to open the hamburger menu
          <div class="mobile-navigation open"> // The "open" class is appended with 
                                               // jQuery when menu is clicked.
          <div id="navigation">            
            <ul style="margin-top: 25px;">
              <li>List item </li>
              <li>List item </li>
              <li>List item </li>
              <li>List item </li>
              <li>List item </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery I have is this (hunted it down on another website and had to figure out from their code which parts were relevant):

```
function ScrollMenuMobile(){
$('.mobile-navigation.open').css('height', $(window.height() + 'px'));
}

$(document).ready(ScrollMenuMobile);
$(document).resize(ScrollMenuMobile);
```

Can't seem to get it to work. The css attribute is never entered within .mobile-navigation.open and I get the error in Firebug:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(document).ready(ScrollMenuMobile);
```

You can click on the hamburger menu and check it out here:

www.prometrika.com/newPMK

Have searched for hours and tried everything. Jsfiddles are great to point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.mobile-navigation.open')` is undefined because your div has 2 separate classes: `mobile-navigation`, and `open`. They are not the same.

Try selecting it via `$('.mobile-navigation')`.